# Unable to access the json image data

Tags: android, node.js, express

I tried to insert an image to db and get back as json data for mobile developing. I can successfully insert the path and retrieve the path as json but when i my friend tried to access the url it shows no such file or found.
This is the code

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var fs = require("fs");
var sql=require('mysql');
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// app.use(bodyParser());
    var multer = require('multer');

    // var upload=multer({dest:'tmp/'});

    // app.use(express.static('public'));

   var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'C:/Users/Ramachandran/Desktop/File/tmp/upload')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var con=sql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:'',
    database:'test'
});



app.get('/',function (req,res){
    con.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    console.log("connection established");
    res.send("connection established");
});

})

app.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html',{'root': __dirname });
})


app.post('/insert', upload.single("myfile"), function (req,res){

    var tes = __dirname + "/" + req.file.originalname;

     fs.writeFile(tes, data, function (err) {
        if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var response = {
                        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                        filename: req.file.originalname
                    };
                }
                console.log(response);
            });

    var data = {
        uid:req.body.RollNo,
        pat:req.file.path
    };


    con.query("insert into src set ?",data, function (err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send("Value has bee inserted");
    })


})

app.get('/test',function(req,res){
    con.query('select * from src',function (err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("data receive from db");
        console.log(rows);
        res.send(rows);
    })
})
```

app.listen(8888);

This my Json data

```
[{"uid":78965,"pat":"C:\\Users\\Vasanth\\Desktop\\File\\tmp\\upload\\myfile-1467012273947"},{"uid":987,"pat":"C:\\Users\\Vasanth\\Desktop\\File\\tmp\\upload\\myfile-1467012387236"}]
```

Comment: avoid using local path "C:\\Users\\Vasanth\\Desktop\\File\\tmp\\upload\\myfile-1467012273947"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work as you are returning a local path. The file is present on your machine, but when your friend tries to download it, he is trying to find it in `C:\\Users\\Vasanth\\Desktop\\File\\tmp\\upload\\myfile-1467012273947` on his machine. You need to save the file on a folder, that is exposed by the server and provide the file from there, i.e. - `http://localhost:8888/files/myfile-1467012273947` The easiest way to achieve this is using the `express.static` middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply [{"uid":4521,"pat":"tmp\\e81a365801e3ee1eb9d7ae8e6b62e471"}] is this correct url... if so it's also didn't work.. u can c my code i've used the express static but that didn't work well for me.

Comment: Please take a look at the `express.static` middleware as it will help you serve the files